# textarea does not read php code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Lately, I have been fond of live code editors such as [cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and I want to replicate my own with one small twist: php code.

The basic elements behind these live code editors are textarea, javascript, and an iframe. You can see the final results either via js script or php form. I went through the js script route, and it works fine for html, css, and js, but not php; the site shows up empty like nothing been entered. When I went the php form route, I got the same results. with php forms, however, I have the ability to create/write php files, which would then display the code correctly, but that would remove the live editing function. I'm wondering if you know any other routes to finish the intended project besides the ones above. Also, I tried

```
<?php
$codeInput = stripslashes($_POST['code']);
?>
```

and that turned nothing.

Comment: show us some code to make us understand ur problem easily

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/ ?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`. And get rid of `stripslashes`. If you don't know what either does, or how to utilize your browsers »view source«, then you should hold out with recreating a live code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [**`htmlspecialchars`**](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), not [**`stripslashes`**](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

`htmlspecialchars` is specifically for encoding things like `<`, as in `<?php`.

`stripslashes` only removes backslashes (`\`).

Be very careful with this, however; directly outputting unfiltered user input can lead to XSS attacks, even if you use `htmlspecialchars`. [Read more here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

As an aside, you probably don't need to roll your own editor for this. You might check out http://ideone.com/ instead, which is basically a jsFiddle for PHP and a large number of other languages.